# Share Preference package of flutter show error after update

Tags: flutter, share, preferences

I am using Share Preference package for my flutter application but it show follwoing errors

Plugin `path_provider_linux` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation in pubspec.yaml.

To set a default implementation, use:
flutter:
plugin:
platforms:
linux:
default_package:

To implement an interface, use:
flutter:
plugin:
implements:

Plugin `path_provider_windows` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation in pubspec.yaml.

To set a default implementation, use:
flutter:
plugin:
platforms:
windows:
default_package:

To implement an interface, use:
flutter:
plugin:
implements:

Plugin `shared_preferences_linux` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation in pubspec.yaml.

To set a default implementation, use:
flutter:
plugin:
platforms:
linux:
default_package:

To implement an interface, use:
flutter:
plugin:
implements:

Plugin `shared_preferences_macos` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation in pubspec.yaml.

To set a default implementation, use:
flutter:
plugin:
platforms:
macos:
default_package:

To implement an interface, use:
flutter:
plugin:
implements:

Plugin `shared_preferences_windows` doesn't implement a plugin interface, nor sets a default implementation in pubspec.yaml.

To set a default implementation, use:
flutter:
plugin:
platforms:
windows:
default_package:

To implement an interface, use:
flutter:
plugin:
implements:

/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Error: Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Error: Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Error: Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Error: Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Error: Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Error: Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Error: Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class CLSID extends Struct {}
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Error: Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class STATSTG extends Struct {}
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4+1/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Error: Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Error: Struct 'Utf8' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class Utf8 extends Struct {
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Error: Struct 'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs are undefined behavior.
class Utf16 extends Struct {
^
/D:/Software/android/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error: Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
final int totalSize = count * sizeOf();
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\Software\android\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\Software\android\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Flutter master channel, [switch to dev or beta](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading#switching-flutter-channels). [This is a known issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70942).

Answer (score 1):

[image: Just add this in pubspec.yaml]

Just add this in your pubspec.yaml

Link to the latest versions :

shared_preferences
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

path_provider_linux
https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider_linux/latest/

path_provider_macos
https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider_macos/latest/

path_provider_windows
https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_windows

shared_preferences_linux
https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences_linux/latest/

shared_preferences_macos
https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences_macos/latest/

shared_preferences_windows
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences_windows

Its works !!! i hope that is help you !!!